# Asp .Net Core Controller Task timing out

Tags: asp.net-core, background-service

I have an ASP .NET Core 3.1 website that imports data. Prior to importing, I want to run some validation on the import. So the user selects the file to import, clicks 'Validate', then either gets some validation error messages so they can fix the import file, or allows them to import.

The problem I am running into is around the length of time these validation and import processes take. If the file is small, everything works as expected. If the file is larger (Over 1000) records the validation and/or may take several minutes. On my local machine, or a server on my network, this works fine. On my actual public facing website, I am getting:

```
503 first byte timeout
```

So, I need some strategies for getting around this. Turning up the timeout time seems like a rabbit hole?  It looks like BackgroundService/IHostedService is probably the best way to go? But I cant seem to find an example of how to do this in the way I would like:

1. Call "Validate" via AJAX
2. Turn on a loader
3. Perform validation
4. Turn off loader
5. Display either success or list of errors to user

##UPDATE## -

Validation -

1. Ajax call to controller
2. Controller calls Business Logic code

a. Check file extension

b. check file size

c. Read in .csv with CsvHelper

d. Check that all required columns are present

c. Check that required columns contain valid data - length, no whitespace, valid zip code, valid phone, etc...

d. Check for internal duplicates

e. If append (as opposed to overwrite) check for duplicates in database - this is the slow step

So, is a better solution to speed up the validation process? Is BackgroundService overkill?

Comment: 1. What and how the validation is done  2. Ideally, processing 1000 records shouldn't be an issue 9

Comment: Agree with Sunny re #2 - 1000 records is nothing, any modern DBMS should be able to handle that few in seconds if not milliseconds. Sounds like your queries need optimising. As to the question at hand, an Azure Function with an output binding would likely be a better solution.